# How to print Stata outputs and .tex files

Tags: latex, output, stata, tex

I've some regression in Stata that I would like to have in a table format.  I also have the outputs saved in another map as .tex files, but they look really odd.

My Stata code is as follows

```
esttab DID_eventAlina DID_eventclio DID_eventdiktat DID_eventDRskole  ///
        using "$results/Table2_PanelA.tex", replace label booktabs keep(_IweeXyear_7 ///    
        _IweeXyear_7 _IweeXyear_8 _IweeXyear_9 _IweeXyear_10  _IweeXyear_11  _IweeXyear_12  _IweeXyear_13 _IweeXyear_14) b(2) se(2) r(3) ///
        coeflabel(_IweeXyear_7 "4 weeks before*2020" _IweeXyear_8 "3 weeks before*2020" _IweeXyear_9 "2 week before*2020" _IweeXyear_10 "1 week before*2020" _IweeXyear_11 "week of lockdown*2020" ///
        _IweeXyear_12 "1 week after*2020" _IweeXyear_13 "2 weeks after*2020" _IweeXyear_14 "3 weeks after*2020") ///
        mtitles("Alina" "clio" "diktat" "Drskole" ) ///
        stats(countryFE timeFE, fmt(. . . 0)  ///
        label("Country FE" "Year, Week and Day FE" "observation"))  compress ///
        nonotes star(* 0.1 ** 0.05 *** 0.01) nonumbers
```

And then when I look at the .tex file and open it in LaTeX it looks like this

```
{
\def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}
\begin{tabular}{l*{4}{c}}
\toprule
                &\multicolumn{1}{c}{Alina}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{clio}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{diktat}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Drskole}\\
\midrule
4 weeks before*2020&     0.00         &     0.00         &     0.00         &     0.00         \\
                &      (.)         &      (.)         &      (.)         &      (.)         \\
\addlinespace
3 weeks before*2020&     4.34         &     4.24         &     0.00         &   -10.35         \\
                &   (9.73)         &   (7.77)         &      (.)         &  (27.69)         \\
\addlinespace
2 week before*2020&     4.53         &     1.37         &     0.00         &    32.16         \\
                &   (9.30)         &   (7.07)         &      (.)         &  (30.89)         \\
\addlinespace
1 week before*2020&     1.92         &     4.28         &     0.00         &    25.09         \\
                &   (9.91)         &   (7.24)         &      (.)         &  (21.41)         \\
\addlinespace
week of lockdown*2020&    10.75         &    17.52         &     0.00         &    17.27         \\
                &  (12.72)         &  (12.33)         &      (.)         &  (27.51)         \\
\addlinespace
1 week after*2020&    10.24         &    25.36\sym{**} &     0.00         &     3.00         \\
                &  (11.57)         &  (10.98)         &      (.)         &  (32.10)         \\
\addlinespace
2 weeks after*2020&     0.43         &    24.30\sym{***}&     0.00         &    16.41         \\
                &   (8.90)         &   (8.64)         &      (.)         &  (27.33)         \\
\addlinespace
3 weeks after*2020&    -8.52         &    15.20         &     0.00         &    11.45         \\
                &  (11.93)         &  (15.17)         &      (.)         &  (20.88)         \\
\midrule
Country FE      &      Yes         &      Yes         &      Yes         &      Yes         \\
Year, Week and Day FE&      Yes         &      Yes         &      Yes         &      Yes         \\
observation     &                  &                  &                  &                  \\
N               &      461         &      559         &       13         &       68         \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
}
```

How can I make this a table in a pdf file?

Comment: You need to (install and) run `pdflatex` on the produced `.tex` file to get a pdf. It looks like it doesn't have the preamble (document type declaration and imports), so you may have to `include` it in another `.tex` file.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a page that has only this table, put

```tex
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
```

before what you have and put

```tex
\end{document}
```

after what you have. Then run LaTeX to compile it to produce the PDF file.

[image: PDF result]

Otherwise, just put what you have in the `document` environment, and add `\usepackage{booktabs}` in the preamble (if not present).

Comment: If your question is now resolved, good, and please accept it formally to give @j1-lee and yourself some reputation.